# Disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS cause Error 404.15

Tags: iis-8, aspnetboilerplate

As title, I want to disable `Anonymous Authentication` for my ASP.NET Boilerplate web site (MVC) in IIS Server and use `Form Authentication` instead. Is it possible to do this because if I disable `Anonymous Authentication`, my website cause an error "HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found"

> Update 1: Here is my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/E404" />
    </customErrors>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Give us a little more info: What server are you running? ISS, apache?

Comment: I have updated these info in my question, bro

Comment: Where did you disable the Anonymous Authentication? can you post the config file you used to do this? or just the section you edited.  and maybe the filename

Comment: I have disabled it in IIS, not the config file. The content was added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I still remember the first time I had to implement Forms Authentication in ASP.  All I can say is there is a reason I only do linux based web-development now!

It is a real pain, but this should work if you don't intend on using a database to manage the users.

If you do intend to use a database then prepare yourself for a long road.  U need to have the correct MSSQL database for the correct Visual studio tool and they also removed the management interface completely so you either have to design your own or use a tool that is available on the internet somewhere.  I still remember I got so frustrated by the whole idea of it, that I literally wrote my own management tool I could deploy on developed sites.  If it wasn't on a broken harddrive I would give it to you.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">  
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="welcome.aspx">  
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">  
      <user name="abhishek" password="abhi@123"/>  
      <user name="Kantesh" password="sinha@123" />  
    </credentials>  
  </forms>  
</authentication>  
<authorization>  
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

If you plan on using a database to store your users google some tutorials.

The reason why you are getting a 404 is because you are not specifying loginUrl or it is incorrect and pointing to a non-existant page.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using ASP NET Boiler plate MVC template. I use your configs also but the same issue happen, it say the query string is too long

Answer (score 2):

When you disable anonymous access to all pages you cannot let users to see login page as well. what you need to to do is allowing some specific pages like login or register to be accessible.
This might not completely fits for you but you get the idea.
If it doesn't work, try removing the backslash "/" for the "/account/login" and set it like "account/login"

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />  //this will restrict anonymous user access
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="/account/login"> //path here is path to login page 
   <system.web><authorization><allow users="*" /> // this will allow access to everyone to login page 
 </authorization></system.web></location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried to enable Anonymous Authentication for all folders of my page (except the root Site). But it didnt work, any advise, bro

Comment: It say the query string is too long. The url is " http://localhost:80/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%25"

Comment: that's because it goes into loop between unauthorized pages. Account/login returns to itself. you couldn't manage to grant anonymous access for Account/Login

Comment: So what can I do, bro?

Comment: I have tried to change Account/Login to TestLogin.html and it worked. So do you have any advide, may it related to Boilerplate fw?

Comment: It has nothing to do with AspNet Boilerplate.  Try to create a project from scratch ( a new project without ABP) achieve what you want to do. In that way you can see if ABP has a side-effect to your issue. I say you need to grant anonymous access to Account/Login